# Python: Match employee name with company, age, gender

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, match

Create a function with the following specifications:

Function name: employee_matcher

Purpose: to match the employee name with the provided company, age, and gender

Parameter(s): company (string), age (int), gender (string)

Returns: The employee first_name and last_name like this: return first_name, last_name

Note: If there are multiple employees that fit the same description, first_name and last_name should return a list of all possible first names and last name

```
df_employee = pd.read_json(open('employee_info.json'))
  print(df_employee)
```

## Elements in df_employee

```
     age      company first_name  gender        last_name
0     42      123-reg  Inglebert    Male         Falconer
1     14          163     Rafael    Male         Bedenham
2     31          163     Lemuel    Male             Lind
3     45          163      Penny  Female          Pennone
4     52          163       Elva  Female         Crighton
5     55         1688   Herminia  Female            Sisse
6     30        1und1       Toby  Female           Nisuis
7     36        1und1     Kylynn  Female         Vedikhov
8     37        1und1     Mychal    None          Denison
9     32          360    Angelle  Female           Kupisz
10    35          360     Ilario    Male          Mannagh
```

## Code

This is my attempt.

```
def employee_matcher(company, age, gender):
  match = (df_employee['company'] == company) & (df_employee['age'] == age) & (df_employee['gender'] == gender)

  print(match)

  return list(pd.Series(match['first_name']).values, pd.Series(match['last_name']).values)
```

Note that the print(match) will print out the following output

```
0      False
1      False
2      False
3      False
4      False
5      False
6      False
7      True
8      False
9      False
10     False
```

## Example Run

```
employee_matcher('1und1', 36, 'Female')
```

Example run would be for this line to print out Kylynn Vedikhov

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you have a specific question or problem, write a question on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that match is a mask, you'll need to use the mask to find the rows that satisfy the conditions. i.e. `df_employee[mask]`

here is the modified code

```
def employee_matcher(company, age, gender):
    match = df_employee[(df_employee['company'] == company) & (
        df_employee['age'] == age) & (
        df_employee['gender'] == gender)]
    return (match.first_name + ' ' + match.last_name).values.tolist()
```

the function will return all the first-name/last-names of matching records

```
In []: employee_matcher('1und1', 36, 'Female')
Out[]: ['Kylynn Vedikhov']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This definitely solved the problem.